# How to open a new window from the child window

Tags: javascript

From the main page I would like to open a child window and from the child window I would like to open a another window. how is it possible?
I have tried the below code and its not working.

```
<script type='text/javascript">
function click1(){
var win1=window.open();
win1.document.write("first window");
var windowHTML ='<input type="button" value="click"   onclick="click2()" />';
win1.document.write(windowHTML); 
}    

function click2(){
 var win2=window.open();
 win2.document.write("seccond window");
}
```

​

```
 <input type="button" value="click1" onclick="click1()" />​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

#### 1. Use `opener` in the child

Change

```
var windowHTML ='<input type="button" value="click"   onclick="click2()" />';
```

to

```
var windowHTML ='<input type="button" value="click"   onclick="opener.click2()" />';
// Change is here ---------------------------------------------^
```

`opener` in the child window will be a reference to your main window, and since you're using global functions, they can be called via that reference (assuming that there are no [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issues).

#### 2. Put the code in the child

Alternately, you can put the code you want to trigger in the child window by writing a `script` tag to it (either one that contains inline JavaScript, which is a bit dodgy, or one that references an external file, which would be better).

---

FWIW, I'd recommend stepping back and asking whether you *really* need to use multiple windows rather than sticking to one window and doing "virtual" windows via `div`s and such.

Comment: Thanks it works.yes i agree using one window is a better option but just wanted to know what are the other available options.